# authenticate only from a certain ip possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

Im trying to authenticate based on a certain ip, if the ip is not correct access should be not allowed.

Im using in application_controller:

```
before_filter :authenticate
  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
      username == "admin" && password == "talkmate"
    end
  end
```

What would be the correct way to add checking for IP and disallow access if the ip is not a certain value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check `request.remote_ip`. If it's not right, render error message, or redirect to error page (or something else).